# How to clean a file_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<% if f.object.header_image.present? %>
              <%= image_tag f.object.header_image.url, class:"img-responsive"%>
            <% end %>
            <%=f.file_field :header_image, class:"form-control"%>
```

I can successfully upload new file. But How I can just empty my column?
I have an image set, and now I want to set NO Image for :header_image. Just nil value.
I have just only the "Upload new file" button.

I want let the user choose If he want to add a new photo (and substitute the previous one) or just let an empty field (no photo)

If I just set a nil value, Carrierwave will automatically destroy the picture

Comment: Do you mean passing a nil value to the field? Have you tried `f.file_field(:header_image, class: "form-control", value: nil)` ?

Comment: Yes, But I want let the user choose If he want to add a new photo (and substitute the previous one) or just let an empty field (no photo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your form, if the image is present add a checkbox below the picture that user must check if he want to delete it, then from the controller in the update action you can destroy the picture. Probably there would be another solutions.

Comment: If I just set a nil value, Carrierwave will automatically destroy the picture

Comment: Totally sparkly this is what I meant. Please if this helped you to solve it, accept my answer!